# React: Are classes without state still considered stateless/pure?

Tags: class, reactjs, react-redux

I've been refactoring my app to make more components stateless/pure components; i.e., they're just functions. However, I noticed that some components will need to connect with the redux store via `mapStateToProps`. Which causes me to do something like this:

```
const someComp = (props) => {
  const {
    funcFromReduxStore,
  } = props;

  return (
    ...
    <SomeComponent
      func={ funcFromReduxStore(myArgs) }
    ...
  );
};
```

This will not work because I am executing `funcFromReduxStore`. An easy solution is to wrap the prop in an arrow function. However, this causes many unnecessary re-renders b/c the function won't be bound.

The question then becomes: *How do I bind a function in a stateless component?*

Is it still stateless if I make it a class, without a constructor, and create a class instance field as so:

```
class someComp extends React.Component {
  const {
    funcFromReduxStore,
  } = this.props,

  wrapper = (x) => funcFromReduxStore(x) // equivalent way to bind w/ ES8+

  render() {
    ...
    <SomeCompnent
      func={ wrapper(myArgs) }/>
    ...
  }
}
```

I don't have a constructor, nor state. I want to keep the comopnent stateless, but I also want to bind the function to avoid unncessary re-renders. I also want to continue to keep it stateless b/c React has stated there will be performance benefits for stateless comopnents. Does this qualify as a workaround?

Comment: As per my understanding, a stateless component can still be a class, if you need access to `this`. If you look at Functional and Class components in https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html, the doc says that react considers both of them the same (that particular functional and class example). So as long as state is not altered, its still stateless component maybe not functional. The whole point of functional is just to keep your stateless components very simple.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no. Stateless functional components need to be simple functions.

You should take a look at the [Recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) library for some really cool helpers that allow you to beef up your SFCs.

If you're trying to prevent unnecessary re-renders, you could look into [`onlyUpdateForKeys()`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#onlyupdateforkeys) or [`pure()`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#pure).

**EDIT:** So, I've been thinking about this a bit more and found this really great article on [React component rendering performance](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/component-rendering-performance-in-react-df859b474adc#.c605atp98). One of the key points in that article that pertains to your question:

> Stateless components are internally wrapped in a class without any optimizations currently applied, according to Dan Abramov.

*[From a tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/755343749983657986?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) in July 2016*

So it appears that I was wrong. "Stateless Functional Components" *are* classes...for now. The confusing thing is that there have been [performance improvements theorized](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components):

> In the future, we’ll also be able to make performance optimizations specific to these components by avoiding unnecessary checks and memory allocations.

At this point, I think the answer to your question becomes largely subjective. When you make a class that extends a React Component, any instances of your class get the `setState`prototype method. Meaning you have the ability to set state. So does that mean it's stateful even if you're not using state? Thanks to @Jordan for the [link to the code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/15-stable/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L41-L48). SFCs only get a render method on the prototype when they are wrapped in a class by React.

To your point about wanting to bind functions, there's only two reasons I can think of that you'd want to bind the function:

1. To give the function access to `this` (the instance of the component). From your example, it doesn't seem like you need that.
2. To ensure that the function passed as a prop to a child component always retains the same identity. The `wrapper` function in your example seems unnecessary. The identity of the function is determined by the parent component (or `mapStateToProps`, or whatever HOC).

You should also take a look at React's `PureComponent` which does the same kind of shallow checking that the `pure()` HOC from recompose does.

Comment: Can you direct me to the specific API that would be helpful in this case?

Comment: @AlanH I added a couple of links to some of the HOCs you could look at.

Comment: Well, the underlying goal is to be able to bind in stateless components. Thanks though!

Comment: @AlanH Binding just ensures that the identity of the function doesn't change on subsequent re-renders. Wouldn't you get the same benefits by binding the function in your parent component?

Comment: FWIW the class that stateless functional components are wrapped in [appears to be very minimal](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/15-stable/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L41-L48). As far as I can tell, it's not a full-blown React.Component instance.

Comment: I spent SO long looking for that piece of code. Thanks @Jordan!

Comment: @Bryan Yeah, in a sense the goal is reduce re-renders. But the react-team has stated there will be performance gains with stateless components, so I'd like to keep the comopnents pure.